# Aws timestream cost when querying only the last entry

Tags: amazon-timestream

In my scenario I have a aws timeseries table and for a specific dimension I need the most recent entry . I will still be charged a total of 10MB data scanned for this ? Is there a way to reduce or circumvent this cost ?

Comment: Apparently! I am not happy about minimum 10MB per query pricing as well because I have lots of tiny queries and I being charged for very unfairly. Bring it up to AWS support. We should try to get our voice heard! Maybe they can make the pricing more sensible for applications with small queries. Everyone tries to optimize their queries to return only the amount of data required and we are getting penalized for that!

Comment: You can use dynamoDb. It can handle time series very well and queries are quite cheap. It worked very well in my case.